# Install4j installer stops just before first Welcome Screen with NullPointerException

Tags: java, install4j

We have an install4j installer that is stopping at the end of the "is preparing the install4j wizard" phase and just before the "Welcome to the ... Setup Wizard" screen. This has happened with two customers (out of thousands), both running Windows 7. It has never happened before and we have been using install4j for many years. The installer does not hang - you can cancel out of it. It just stops. We got the following from one of the log files. We have sent out replacement CDs that have been checked, etc. We have tried "run as administrator". Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Dimension.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.ArrangeGrid(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.arrangeGrid(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.wizard.WizardBase.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.wizard.WizardBase.showFrame(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.WizardScreenExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Dimension.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.ArrangeGrid(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.arrangeGrid(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.wizard.StandardScreen$1.componentResized(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This is a problem between the JRE and the Windows installation. Do you bundle a JRE? What version is it?

Comment: Ingo, ben75's suggestion solved the problem (using a different theme during installation). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more than probably caused by a specific (custom ?) look&feel on customer computer. So if they reset the look&feel to the default one, it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar stack trace, and following on from the answer from ben75 above found the following in the Install4J help ( http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/index.html )

-Dinstall4j.nolaf=true

This solved my problem with an installer running on some Windows 7 and Windows 8 systems.